# Differential BPSK vs BPSK what are the advantages and disadvantages?

Tags: digital-communications, digital

Recently I have come across different variation of the sane modulation techniques. I am quite confused about the advantages of different constellations. In particular, what are the advantages of using

Differential BPSK over BPSK?

Any thoughts?

Comment: "Any thoughts?"  Yes. When is your homework due?

Comment: This is not my homework, if you notice my questions are at higher level than homeworks.@DilipSarwate

Comment: I have _not_ noticed that your questions (here as well as on math.SE) are at a higher level than homework questions. I have a lifetime's experience in _creating_ homework questions and asking them of students and am perfectly capable of judging the level of questions. The _flood_ of recent questions from you (more than 25 since mid-April) supports my hypothesis that you are taking a course in digital communications (and possibly a separate one in coding theory) and are getting all your homework answers here (and on math.SE).

Comment: As I said this is not my homework with all respect to your experience. I am trying to learn. If you believe this annoying for you, please do not answer and avoid my questions. @DilipSarwate

Comment: Regrettably, many of the questions that you have _inundated_ this forum (and math.SE and stats.SE) with _are_ in my areas of interest. I have lived all my life with the firm belief that there is no such thing as a stupid question, but I am thinking that maybe this belief needs some updating.

Comment: ofcourse there is :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Differential BPSK**

As the information is encoded in the phase difference of two consecutive symbols, phase estimation can be omitted in systems where the carrier phase can be assumed to be constant during two symbols. Specifically, it can be used in a self-coherent receiver which mixes one symbol with its predecessor in order to reconstruct the phase difference between the two symbols. In such a scheme, no local oscillator is required which simplifies the system (e.g. frequency synchronization is not needed).

**Non-differential (coherent) BPSK**

In differential BSPK, two symbols are "added" and as a consequence the noise of the two symbols adds up. This results in a 3 dB sensitivity gain of coherent BPSK. In other words, coherent BPSK is more robust against noise.

Comment: Thank you Deve. What do you mean by two symbols are added? If I want to send a 0 I send s0 and if I want to send bit 1 I send s1. Not sure what you meant by added. Do you mean at the receiver?

Comment: Now this is another question, namely "How does differential BPSK work?" which cannot be answered by comments. Can you read up on differential modulation and come back with specific questions?

Comment: Sure, but the term "added" you used in the non-differential BPSK and not in the differential case?

Comment: I used it referring to differential BPSK. It's a sloppy formulation, therefore I put it inside quotes.

Comment: Sorry I meant your answer should have been: *In non-differential (coherent) BSPK, two symbols are "added" and as a consequence the noise of the two symbols adds up. This results in a 3 dB sensitivity gain of coherent BPSK. In other words, coherent BPSK is more robust against noise*

Comment: No, because this would be wrong. I meant it like I said it.

Comment: I have chosen this admittedly clumsy formulation because I wanted to present the advantage of the two schmes in the respective paragraph.